# Rails Active Storage, delete file from S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage to upload images to S3 bucket. Everything is working fine but when I am deleting image file from console then file is not deleted from S3 bucket. Rails documentation says that using `purge` will delete file from S3 bucket as well. But in my case I can still see the file in S3 bucket. Below are the commands which I am using to delete file from console.

```
company = Company.first
company.logo.purge # this is deleting the file in console but not deleting file in S3 bucket.
```

when I check the log from rails server then its saying deleting from Disk Storage rather than S3. Below is my log.

```
Disk Storage (0.4ms) Deleted file from key: 1x29cv8bkur97n3fosu9qwfx8316
Disk Storage (0.1ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/1x29cv8bkur97n3fosu9qwfx8316/
```

So how can I delete the file from S3 bucket using rails console.

**UPDATE:** I don't know what was the problem but restarting my rails console fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but restarting my rails console fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this might be the IAM role attached to the application server might not have the permissions to delete a file from S3. Check the allowed resources as well as allowed methods on the IAM policy